# Rails: Ajax-enabled form without a model object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails and having a hard time figuring out how to create a form that submits over Ajax without having a corresponding model object.

My use case is a simple form that collects an email address and sends it an email; there's nothing to be persisted, so no model.

In cases where I *do* have a model, I've had success with `form_for(@model, remote: true)`. I can't seem to find the right helper for the case where there is no model. I tried `form_tag(named_path, remote: true)` and that works, but does not use Ajax.

Pointers to an example with an example with a proper controller, `.html.erb` and `routes.rb` would be really appreciated.

Comment: "it works but it doesn't use ajax". what do you mean by that? it generates a non-remote form and posts data normally?

Comment: Yes- it posts normally, but then reloads the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I solved it. The key was using `form_tag` and specifying a hash with an argument that properly matched my route. For my business logic, I need to pass in an "id" param, which is used in the controller logic.

```
<%= form_tag(sendmail_path({ id: 1}), remote: true) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Send", remote:true %>
<% end %>
```

`routes.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  post '/sendmail/:id(.:format)' => 'mycontroller#sendmail', :as => 'sendmail'
  # etc...
end
```

I also had to supply a sendemail.js.erb template which updates the form after submission.